# Invalid Host header?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, codesandbox

Ребята, при запуске проекта Vue, импортированного из репозитория в codesandbox, в браузере выходит: Invalid Host header

Подскажите пожалуйста. Гуглил, подходящего не нашёл, Решение со свойством - disableHostCheck: true, файле vue.config.js не работает...

```
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true, // НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
  },
});
```